# previously able to get photo and video, now Unable to get them from Firebase database with the same code

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I was able to get photo and video from firebase database week ago. Now, I could not. There is no crash and no error, I managed to get the text data only but unable to load the images into UiCollectionView.

I really dont know what are the issues causing this. Please kindly extend your help.

I have these in my pod file:
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

here the code for UICollectionView and use Extension on ImageView to download image:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: seasonCoverImage.identifier, for: indexPath) as! seasonCoverImage
            
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
            
            let im = seasons[indexPath.row]
            
            cell.ImageViewCover.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cell.ImageViewCover.clipsToBounds = true
            
            cell.ImageViewCover.download(from: im.ImageUrl!)
            cell.TitleLbSeason.text = im.Season
            
            return cell

 }


--
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIImageView {

func downloadnow(from url: URL, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                //- this imageView itself
                self?.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func download(from link: String, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFill) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }       
        downloadnow(from: url, contentMode: mode)
    }

}

- additional note:

1.create folder in Firebase storage
The photo or images are stored in the folder in Firebase storage

2. get file with access token
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxx/o/xxxx%2image_1.jpg?alt=media&token=e62xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx

store this url of image filename in Firebase database

Seasons
  |
  |-FourSeasonsPhoto
     |
     |- ImgURL <-- for the url of the image file
     |- Desc
     |- other ...

3. use this to access the image file

let seasonsRef = Database.database().reference().child("Seasons")
        
let seasonImgRef = seasonsRef.child("FourSeasonsPhoto")

why this was working before and not now??
```

Comment: Are your files on Firebase Storage? If so, you should use Firebase's api to download files: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files?

Comment: @Asteroid please read my additional note of how i access the file using the firebase code. Thanks